# Is there a way to lock a point into a curve?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I have a circle as a point and a stroke as a curve. Is it possible to lock the center of the point to the curve so that however I move it the point is still in the curve? In another word, how to make it becomes a slider on the curve?

Comment: Select all of the points you want to move with the Direct Selection tool and move them.

Comment: they aren't really locked in the curve, right?

Comment: PS what you really want is a indirect modeler, neither inkscape or illustrator will make you happy.

Comment: I tried to make an [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/110583/2332), but I didn't read the question after the edit and I realize I misunderstood the question anyways. — Just like your last question, you seem to approach this from a bit of a weird direction. I'm not sure why you'd want this. I can't think of a situation where I would need this functionality... Well Snapping makes sense. Just like in Billy's answer, AI has snapping. So if you use the normal Selection tool to move the circle on top of the other the other path, it should snap to it kinda like magnets.

Comment: @Joonas it might be useful if he wanted to do a lot of same thing. Animation software often allow this, cad applications allow this. But then they arent comming from a drawing background. A direct modeller has some benefits, but indrect modellers have even more benefits.

Comment: @joojaa, what throws me off is the approach, I think. Like why would anyone need to drag a circle along a path? The output is a static image... So why not just drag it to a point and be done with it. Why would you need to slide it around the path. If this was an animation I would totally understand why you'd want to do this, but when the output is a static image, not so much. — I think it may be just a matter of terminology and me not being able to see the big picture.

Comment: @Joonas yes but you might be using this template a 1000 times. It is perfactly valid just not a common mindset of graphic designers. Its the elephant in the room ofr you, you can not see it since your used to it.

Comment: @Joonas and no vector drawing software are not making static images, they are making programs for the rendering engines. Theres no reason to believe that those engines must be stupid.

Comment: @Joonas I would need to slide it a lot to test so I think it's nice to know. My purpose is to create nice illustrations for scientific reports, and I'm still new the designing field much, or the tools to use, or the terms to describe problems, so that's why it would be confusing for experts to understand me. Anyway, thank you for your answers

Comment: Right. It's the fidelity and gradualness of sliding an object along a path that is something that designers don't necessarily need. I mean I would use this "Lock object or point to a path" feature it if it was a thing, but in general moving things from point A to point B _visually_ is good enough for designers. I can see how in a scientific report it would make more sense so you could, for instance, set the circle to be exactly at the 35% mark on the path, or something like that. I wonder if there are other apps that would fulfill your needs better.

Comment: @Joonas there are of course other tools for that, but they lack the aesthetic purpose because, you know, they are not the tool for aesthetic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and No. Both Illustrator and Inkscape are direct modelers. This means you the user are mostly responsible for doing everything yourself.

Even though both applications have some indirect modeling utilities the arent designed as such. So whatever indirection you happen to need then wether it has that one is purely coincidental.

But both can do this if whatever you want to attach can be converted to a font. As both are capable of making text on curve as you describe. Inkscape can also do something like this with arrowheads in a limited 
way, while illustrator can only attach to ends. You can also use art brushes (illustrator) or path effects (inkscape) for this. But really the applications arent meant for this. As placing manually is not a issue in the intended modeling paradigm.

Now there are applications that are meant for indirect modeling that do have these features, in a way that you can reliably expect them to do 99% of everything you need. But for both illustrator and inkscape one could be made to have this feature, though they would never be good indirect modelers. And honestly I have this tool for illustrator implemented in my api feasibility test set, but its still not in a state that anybody other than me could use it.

Comment: Do you mean "indirect modeling" as "[parameter modeling](http://www.concurrent-engineering.co.uk/blog/blog/bid/93709/what-cad-users-need-to-know-about-direct-modeling)"? Is animation an indirect modeling? Image manipulation?

Comment: @Ooker indirect is bigger than the set pf parametric modeling. But yeah most 3d animation software are on average indirect modellers, though they can often be used directly too, which your average parametroic CAD can not do!.But even so direct animation tools exist, you draw each image.

Answer (score 5):

Inscape has snapping features that could help you place the shape on a path precisely, although not physically locked to it.

Enable the following snapping options in the Snap Controls Bar:

- Enable Snapping
- Snap Nodes, Paths and Handles
- Snap to Paths
- Snap other Points (centres, guide origins, gradient handles, etc)
- Snap Centres of Objects

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can't tie points or objects to paths, but in some situations, you can get around this by using Direct Selection tool.

With the Direct Selection tool, you are just picking what points to move, rather than "locking" some points to others. It's not exactly the same, but it can achieve the same thing.

The annoying thing is that in some situations it may be difficult to select just the points you need if there are other points close by. So you may have to hold down `Shift` key and add the points you wish to move to your selection one by one. Ideally, you would just drag out a selection to get all the points at once.

**How you can select the points you need a bit easier:**

1. Lock unimportant **Objects** → Top menu > `Object > Lock`.

   - If you lock an object, it can't be selected anymore.
   - It may make sense to use the normal `Selection tool` to select objects when locking them. Direct selection tool drills inside masks and that may make selecting layers groups harder for this purpose.
   - `Object > Unlock All` to release locked objects.
2. Hide unimportant **Objects** → Top menu > `Object > Hide > Selection`.

   - It may make sense to use the normal `Selection tool` to select objects when hiding them. Direct selection tool drills inside masks and that may make selecting layers groups harder for this purpose.
   - `Object > Unlock All` to release locked objects.
3. Lock unimportant **Layers** in the Layers panel.

   - Same thing. Lock a layer and you can't select it anymore.
4. Hide unimportant **Layers** in the Layers panel.

   - Hiding layers can be way better because AI still tries to snap to locked layers.

Gif of the ideal situation, where there are no extra points surrounding the ones you want to move:

[image]

Gif of a situation of where there is something below so the points I want to move are surrounded by other points making selection difficult. This is a situation where you should start using locks and hiding:

[image]

Now here's another possible issue. The points that I "attached" to the line are not locked to this exact position in the line, they just happen to be stacked in the same coordinates. So when I move these two points simultaneously, lines drift apart and don't stay connected. This is unfortunate but you can't really do much about it:

[image]

Here's a gif where select the line using Direct Selection tool add points to the line using Pen tool. Then I move the points in a similar way and the 2 stacked points stay together, but obviously, it doesn't look the same visually:

[image]

Comment: I considered deleting this answer, but given that it answers the question in the title: "Is there a way to lock a point into a curve?", I figured it may help some people who end up here from a search. Feel free to downvote it so that it gets sorted below the other two answers.

Comment: To be honest the question was not that clear. There are probably several ways it could be interpreted.  It seems all 3 of us who answered understood it quite differently. Leave your answer, it's still useful!